# Extra horizontal space with titlesec's runin style and microtype

Tags: spacing, titlesec, microtype

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{microtype}

\titleformat{\section}[runin]{}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\section{}
Text

Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see from the picture above, the first line has some slight extra horizontal space before the text (barely noticeable in this example, but surely exist).

It is hard to produce a real example, but this phenomenon can be severe in some cases. Below is a screenshot from a course note I'm writing, which led me to find this problem (the first letter "C" should in fact start at the beginning of the line):

[image]

(*in the real document I've put the section numbering into margin, but empty setting as the MWE above is suffice to produce this issue.*)

If I remove `microtype`, the problem seems to be gone. But `microtype` can be really useful, the document looks much better overall with this package.

Why is this happening, and is there some way to fix this behavior?

Comment: A sledgehammer fix is to set [protrusion=no] for microtype. You still get font expansion. // I am honestly a bit surprised at the "real life" example you showed: that seems too much of an indent to be coming from font protrusion only.

Comment: @WillieWong I'm really confused. Both of your suggestions work for the MWE (by the way, did you mean `protrusion=false`?), but not for my original document. Something else must be the reason for this severe behavior, which I'm not able to locate yet. Working on producing a new MWE...

Comment: I meant false; typo there. Thanks for catching it.

Comment: you want `\leftprotrusion` before the first "Test". However, that wouldn't fix the result in your screenshot, which must have a different cause.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is (I think) that `titlesec` puts in a `\strut` when printing section headings. (Read `titlesec.sty` for details.)

If you compile the code below

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{microtype}

\titleformat{\section}[runin]{}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\section{Text}~

\vspace{-1.7em}
Text


\section{}Text

\vspace{-1.7em}
Text

\strut Text

\vspace{-1.7em}
Text
\end{document}
```

You see that the amount of horizontal offset are the same.

[image]

To solve this, the `nostruts` option to `titlesec` seems relevant (May break other things? I dunno.) Unfortunately, it only works on `lualatex`? Here's the `lua` version with the `nostruts` option

[image]

You see you have good alignment in the first two cases, while the `\strut`ed version still shows the offset. But it doesn't work with `pdflatex`. So at this point I give up.

Comment: Thank you, this might be one of the reasons. However, I'm already using `lualatex` but the macro `\nostruts` nor the package option `nostruts` do not make much difference to my original document `:(`

Comment: @Jinwen ... this means that your MWE is not in fact a MWE :-) (I'm sure you can confirm that the code I posted does what it says it does.) Can you go back and make one that still shows the issue with `nostruts`?

Comment: Ah, I figured it out. I've mistakenly added some extra glue to the title spacing, which is wrong for style like `runin`. After removing it, the extra space is now barely seen by human eyes. Anyway, thank you for the effort, also, `\nostruts` is probably a good idea in `lualatex` for the `runin` style.

Answer (score 0):

More or less a hack, but you can solve the problem adding a negative space via the optional argument of `\titleformat`:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \usepackage{parskip}
    \usepackage{microtype}
    \usepackage{showframe}
    \renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.4pt}

    \titleformat{\section}[runin]{}{}{0pt}{}[\hspace*{-0.4pt}]
    \titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{\baselineskip}{0pt}

    \begin{document}

    \section{}Text

    Text

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is that this extra horizontal space is not fixed, it depends on the content that follows. Usually this space is barely noticeable, but in some rare cases it can be quite large (it seems that something is stretching the text and this space is the result of the stretching).

Comment: @Jinwen; Could you post an example code?

Comment: I'm sorry, but the MWE in the question is the best I can provide for now. I've tried to adjust the font or to add math equations in the text like in my real document, but I cannot reproduce the large space that was seen in the real document. The problem is that how `microtype` stretch the text seems a little random to me, it probably requires something at the line break to produce a underfull \hbox to produce a larger extra space.